# PHP : Matching strings between two strings

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem with `preg_match` , i cant figure it out.

let the code say it :

```
function::wp_statistics_useronline::end
function::wp_statistics_visitor|today::end
function::wp_statistics_visitor|yesterday::end
function::wp_statistics_visitor|week::end
function::wp_statistics_visitor|month::end
function::wp_statistics_visitor|total::end
```

these are some string that run functions inside php;

when i use just one `function::*::end` it works just fine.
but when it contain more than one function , not working the way i want
it parse the match like :

```
function::wp_statistics_useronline::end function::wp_statistics_visitor|today::end AND ....::end
```

so basically i need `Regex` code that separate them and give me an `array` for each `function::*::end`

Comment: i would just use explode()

Comment: `Explode` is not pretty for whole thing , i guess. i used `regex`for first action and then `explode` function `parameters` with `explode` @Dagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you were actually using `function::(.*)::end` since `function::*::end` is never going to work (it can only match strings like `"function::::::end"`).

The reason your regex failed with multiple matches on the same line is that the quantifier `*` is greedy by default, matching as many characters as possible. You need to make it lazy: `function::(.*?)::end`

Comment: Hey, this is what i currently use. `preg_match("/function::(.*)::end/",$CurrentSotoun['content'],$calling_function);` any problem that you see ?

Comment: Yes, the quantifier is greedy. Did you notice the `?` in my suggested solution?

Comment: We have a winner here !! its really helped me out , its hours that i working on it and its solved NOW ! thanks alot !

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward:

```
$result = preg_match_all('~function::(\S*)::end~m', $subject, $matches) 
          ? $matches[1] : [];
```

Which gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => wp_statistics_useronline
    [1] => wp_statistics_visitor|today
    [2] => wp_statistics_visitor|yesterday
    [3] => wp_statistics_visitor|week
    [4] => wp_statistics_visitor|month
    [5] => wp_statistics_visitor|total
)
```

And (for the second example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => wp_statistics_useronline
    [1] => wp_statistics_visitor|today
)
```

The regex in the example is a matching group around the part in the middle which does not contain whitespace. So `\S*` is a good fit.

As the matching group is the first one, you can retrieve it with `$matches[1]` as it's done after running the regular expression.

Comment: That's not going to work on the second example, which is the one he is having problems with.

Comment: Then it's `\S` insead of `.` I'd say. Didn't see that string... Edited.

Comment: that seems exactly what i want , but i just tested it , not working

Comment: @user2077916: Please see the edit. I tested it against the data you have provided and both examples work.

Comment: Sorry , i tested it again , works fine , but i prefer to use the selected answer. thank you for sharing.again :)

Comment: Actually , the selected answer just work with your answer ! i should use both answers ! thanks ! @hakre

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

> function\:\:(.*?)\:

Make sure you have the dot matches all identifier set.

After you get the matches, run it through a forloop and run an explode on "|", push it to an array and boom goes the dynamite, you've got what you're looking for.